# Creating New Gmail Account

Tags: gmail

Can you create a new Gmail account without linking it to your current Gmail account? I would like to create a new account with a new email address for an event, but I do not want it linked to my current one.

Comment: Have you tried doing it? Logging out of your current account and going [here](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail)? The field _Your current email address_ is not mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can. A current account is not required to create a new Gmail account. It is optional.